# Trouble loading view when using size classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xcode6, size-classes

I'm having this weird problem with size classes.

I noticed that any UIView which isn't installed in `Any-Any` size class is not part of the subviews when viewDidLoad is called.
Meaning I don't have access to it via my outlet nor does it appear in the `[self.view subviews]` array.

The subviews are placed fine on screen, and the first time I get to access them is in `viewDidAppear`.

I'm developing my app only for portrait iPhones so I set my Storyboard for compact width and regular height.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need my storyboard to support Any-Any even though I don't really use this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

AutoLayout hasn't completed until after the final `viewDidLayoutSubviews` call just before `viewDidAppear`.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    //Do your job with views or with its constraints... 
}
```

Comment: You didn't explain the different behavior in different size classeses

Answer (score 1):

You need your storyboard to support Any-Any even though you don't really use this configuration.
You have to enable Size Classes in Interface Builder, to do that please refer the following link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH1-SW1